# TYPO3 9.5: Plugin RouteEnhancers Nested Arguments

Tags: typo3, url-routing, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I use the extension tx_sfeventmgt_pievent in my TYPO3, but this generates ugly URLs like:

```
?tx_sfeventmgt_pievent[overwriteDemand][month]=1&tx_sfeventmgt_pievent[overwriteDemand][year]=2020&cHash=q76r9wfs0gv
```

I try to route this to something nicer like:

```
/2020/1(or later january)/
```

but the nested arguments don't get evaluated. My config.yaml looks like:

```
routeEnhancers:
  KalenderPlugin:
    type: Plugin
    limitToPages: [45]
    namespace: 'tx_sfeventmgt_pievent'
    routePath: '/{year}/{month}/{hash}'
    _arguments:
      overwriteDemand/month: '[0-9]{1..2}'
      overwriteDemand/year: '[0-9]{4}'
```

The pageid 45 must open without arguments (the extension uses the current date), but when I call /2020/1/, I want it as the `GET` parameter so the extension shows the other month of the year.
How does the config.yaml have to look like?

Comment: It looks like you mixed up the `_arguments` configuration with `requirements`. The `_arguments` config is for mapping route parameters (your `{year}`, `{month}`, etc.) onto the parameters expected by your plugin.
So if anything, it should be something like: `_arguments: {month: 'overwriteDemand/month', year: 'overwriteDemand/year'}`

Comment: When i use it like this:
````routePath: '/{year}/{month}/'

    _arguments: {month: 'overwriteDemand/month', year: 'overwriteDemand/year'}````
i get an error 404 page not found, but the building links are correct

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try with this `config.yaml` where the defaults might not be necessary but I added them for showing a complete configuration.

```
routeEnhancers:
  KalenderPlugin:
    type: Plugin
    limitToPages: [45]
    namespace: 'tx_sfeventmgt_pievent'
    routePath: '/{overwriteDemand/year}/{overwriteDemand/month}/{hash}'
    requirements:
      overwriteDemand/year: '[0-9]{4}'
      overwriteDemand/month: '[0-9]{1..2}'
    defaults:
      overwriteDemand/year: '2020'
      overwriteDemand/month: '10'
      hash: ''
```